# How much base current do I need for a 12V supply with a 400Ω collector load?

Tags: transistors

I'm working with high voltages. I want a red light to blink when the potential is on or is still discharging.

I plan to use a neon bulb illuminating a LDR. I haven't quite got the neon limiting resistor figured out because my output voltage can vary.

I have a working circuit, but would like a critique for any suggested changes I should make. I thought the base voltage was a little high. It is simple, but it is a safety issue. I want the red light to blink when the voltage is not discharged to a safe level.

[image]

Comment: The base current will stay below 1 mA, but check you haven't swapped collector and emitter.

Answer (score 1):

With your existing design, there's a good chance that the transistor will never fully switch off, since there's always some base current flowing. This can be remedied with a single resistor, but I'll add two, just to keep the base safe:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdcyPU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 forms a potential divider with R1 and LDR1, which allows base current to fall to zero when the LDR is not illuminated. Without R2, the transistor can't switch off unless LDR1's resistance becomes ridiculously high.

With the values shown, and a transistor with \$\beta \approx 200\$, base potential drops below 0.6V (which will switch off Q1) when LDR1 has a resistance exceeding about 10kΩ. Here's how current through load RL changes as LDR resistance goes from 5kΩ to 20kΩ:

[image]